# UITableViewCell is transparent when not supposed to be

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

My UITableViewCell is being transparent when it's not supposed to be. My table view has a background color and it shows through the table cell, even though they're supposed to be opaque. I'm not sure why this is.

Relevant code:

```
    UITableViewCell *cell = [table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:emptyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:emptyIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = @"Empty";
    cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    return cell;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's because of the CGRectZero.
Try using initWithStyle and use one of the system styles.
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:

Nevertheless, initWithFrame is already deprecated.

Comment: Doesn't help. Actually I started out with initwithstyle, but that didn't work, so I went back to some older code to see if that worked. In any case, it doesn't seem to affect it.

Comment: Doesn't do anything. Did you mean whiteColor? Sadly that doesn't work either.  

In general, the entire text label is messed up and doesn't follow regular subview rules or something. I tried instead setting the backgroundView.backgroundColor to white, and that will end up coloring the borders white, but everything within the label's bounds act as like a window, revealing the background of table underneath.

I basically circumvented the whole situation by not dealing with the tablecell's textLabel, and added a UILabel of my own. Very stupid and hackish though. Makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

in IB, click on the uitableviewcell, then check the "clip subviews" property.